# Access property of Superclass from subclass in VBA

Tags: vba, class, subclass, superclass

I have a class called AI which has a property to access an excel worksheet and another property to access another class called "Columns" that contains a bunch of variables.
AI.WS returns the worksheet.
AI.Columns.[name of column] would return an integer representing the column number with that name. But in the class "Columns" it calls a function which needs the worksheet (AI.WS) in order to know where to look for the column. How would I access the property AI.WS (superclass) from the class AI.Columns (the subclass) in vba?

Comment: One way would be to give the Columns class another property that is Set to the WorkSheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a standard issue I'm surprised that you haven't been able to google the answer.  You give the class columns a property called 'Parent' and pass in the AI object as the parent.  You can then access the AI properties through the 'parent' property of Columns.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm confused about is how I would actually implement this, in the Columns class, If I were to make a Public Property Get Parent(), I still don't know how I would get the original object without creating a new one, and I am confused on how I would leverage this property within the columns class itself?

Comment: You create a property in the columns class called Parent that Gets/Sets an AI object and has a private variable of AI object..  When you create a columns object you then pass in through parent the parent AI class.  You can do this as a public property or through your factory (if you use such a thing).  Thus any reference in the columns class to the private parent member should pull up the intellisense for the AI class.